# textarea loses information after a script is ran

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

First of all, I am totally new to client side web programming. Here is a simplified version of the code i am working with.

In the first part of the script i affect a textarea with the text "Why is this text staying". When the user click on the submit button of the form, i try to change the text area with "Some Other Text\n". But a the end of the script, the first text always comes back and i dont know why. Actually, il looks like the page is reloading at the end of the `GetRandomNumber()` function.

```
<div>
    <form>
        Number of roll: <input type="number" id="numberOfRoll" value="1"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Get random value" onclick="GetRandomNumber()">
    </form>
</div> 
<div>
    <textarea cols="80" rows=20 id="resultArea"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    initResultArea();
    function initResultArea() {
        document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML="Why is this text staying";
    };
    function GetRandomNumber() {
        var output="SomeOtherText\n";
        document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML=output;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button type to `button`, not `submit`

```html
<div>
<form>
    Number of roll: <input type="number" id="numberOfRoll" value="1"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Get random value" onclick="GetRandomNumber()">
</form>
</div> 
<div>
    <textarea cols="80" rows=20 id="resultArea"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    initResultArea();
    function initResultArea() {
        document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML="Why is this text staying";
    };
    function GetRandomNumber() {
        var output="SomeOtherText\n";
        document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML=output;
    };
</script>
```

Because it was set to `submit`, every time you press the button the browser is trying to submit your form to a webpage (which hasn't been defined). It is doing this in addition to calling your function, thus why the page is reloading.

Answer (score 0):

You should change type to button `type="button"` instead of submit it will redirect page.

Another way can use onsubmit form instead of onclick button `<form action="#" onsubmit="return GetRandomNumber()">` and `return false` on `GetRandomNumber()`

```js
initResultArea();
    function initResultArea() {
        document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML="Why is this text staying";
    };
    function GetRandomNumber() {
        var output="SomeOtherText\n";
        document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML=output;
        return false;
    };
```

```html
<div>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return GetRandomNumber()">
    Number of roll: <input type="number" id="numberOfRoll" value="1"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Get random value">
</form>
</div> 
<div>
    <textarea cols="80" rows=20 id="resultArea"></textarea>
</div>
```